# How do you use the word "minuscule" in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, nouns, quantifiers

I do not know how to use the word minuscule in a sentence. I want to know what to say when I find an apple at the marketplace and do not want it because it is smaller than other apples there. I tried to say this to my teacher but she said it wasn't right but I don't know why.

> This apple is a such a **minuscule** and I do not want to buy it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From my experience, it tends to be used contextually in that it's often used when the main emphasis is on the size, or lack thereof.  "Even after eating at the restaurant, I'm still hungry as the portions were minuscule."  At least that's how I understand it, I could be wrong.  I guess you could say "Look at that minuscule ant walking along the sidewalk", but it seems like an unnecessary addition when the size isn't the highlight of the sentence.

Comment: The way you used it in your sentence made it sound as if minuscule is a noun. Minuscule is an adjective used to describe something, not something you can physically touch. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minuscule is an adjective, not a noun. Your sentence should be "This apple is minuscule and I don’t want to buy it".

However, minuscule may not be the right word, depending on the context and what you're trying to say. Calling something minuscule means it is extremely small, similar (but not identical) to microscopic. I’d suggest saying, "this apple is unusually small and I don’t want it" because it is a phrase that is more commonly used. Using "minuscule" is completely valid but I and other English speakers may not use this word in this context.

Comment: How would you use minuscule properly?

Comment: @Maury "The minuscule virus was able to move in between the molecules that make up the cell’s membrane because of its size."

Comment: _"However, minuscule is not the right word"_ Sure it is. You're taking things too literally. It is not equivalent to "microscopic". Indeed, the term used to be used for a style of ink writing.

Comment: @Maury: See above.

Comment: Minuscule is not _usually_ a noun. It can be, meaning lowercase writing, or a lowercase letter. It is not often used in that sense anymore.

Comment: Agreeing with Light Races in Orbit, [MW has the adjective definition of miniscule](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minuscule) to simply be "very small", which totally makes sense (though I can think of a few good uses for tiny apples).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've never heard anyone refer to an apple as minuscule. Sure there's nothing wrong with using minuscule, but since the OP is obviously a new English speaker I would recommend using a more common word or phrase until he has a more firm grasp of the language.

Comment: @Jake: As a native speaker, I can assure you that the use of the term "minuscule" to mean "very small" across a broad range of contexts is absolutely common and normal, and thus appropriate for teaching to a new English speaker. I would _not_ recommend teaching the OP things that aren't true (until he has a more firm grasp of the language?!). Mind you, my remaining level of interest in this question is fairly minuscule ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm also a native English speaker. There's nothing wrong with using minuscule in the OP's sentence; I just wanted to suggest something that was a little more common and casual. I'm sorry you feel my answer is untrue. I will edit my answer to reflect this difference of opinion. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: _"minuscule is not the right word"_ "_There's nothing wrong with using minuscule in the OP's sentence"_ You've contradicted yourself, even, so now perhaps you can see why I might say your answer is incorrect. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I personally feel that minuscule isn't the right word. Would 99.99% of English speakers understand him if he used minuscule? Yes. Does minuscule mean what he wants it to? Probably. Does minuscule have a different meaning than unusually small? Yes. I'm not trying to argue with you about this: neither of us is wrong. I just didn't (and still don't) feel that minuscule was the right word and wanted to bring this to the OP's attention. There are tons of words that mean very similar things but they all have different usage and connote differently. That's all.

Comment: Thanks you for all of the comments. I asked my teacher today and she said that I shouldn't use minuscule like this but if I really want to I can. Thank you Lightness and Jake for helping me.

Answer (score -2):

“This change to our policy had only a minuscule effect.”

<s>“Normal writing uses more minuscule than majuscule letters.”</s>

Comment: The terms "minuscule" and "majuscule" are not widely used in common speech that way; use "lowercase" and "uppercase" (or "capital") instead.

Comment: You could even say _Normal writing uses more minuscules than majuscules._ but as Kevin notes correctly, those words are not often used in that sense anymore.

Comment: I would classify those terms as typographical jargon. It's not really old fashioned or archaic per se, it's just a more formal or technical name for what most people call "lowercase" or "small" letters and "uppercase" or "capital" letters.

Comment: I thought of it because *majuscule* in this sense recently came up in conversation — in French.